# Foreach a serialized Dropdown Multiselect from database

Tags: php, multi-select

I have a multiselect dropdown that stores the data in an array and inserts by serialize () to the database. I wonder how I can bring this data back to your checkboxs marked like the image. Can anyone help me please?

[image: Dropdown Multiselect]

Insert:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO programacao 
  (programacao_id, painel_id, palestrante_id, tipo_programacao_id, dia,hora_inicio,hora_fim, palestrantes, imagem,cor_fundo,ativo) 
  VALUES
  (:programacao_id, :painel_id, :palestrante_id, :tipo_programacao_id, :dia,:hora_inicio,:hora_fim,:palestrantes, :imagem,:cor_fundo,:ativo)";
  $dadosBind = array(
    'programacao_id' => $novo_id,
    'painel_id' => $painel_id,
    'palestrante_id' => $palestrante_id,
    'tipo_programacao_id' => $tipo_programacao_id,
    'dia' => $uteis->dataBr2Bd($dia),
    'hora_inicio' => $hora_inicio,
    'hora_fim' => $hora_fim,
    'palestrantes' => serialize($palestrantes),
    'imagem' => ( isset($nome_final_foto) )?$nome_final_foto  :'',
    'cor_fundo' => $cor_fundo,
    'ativo' => $ativo
  );
  $insertProgramacao = $db->ubQuery($sql, $dadosBind);
```

Listing:

```
$sql = "SELECT palestrantes.palestrante_id, palestrantes.nome FROM palestrantes INNER JOIN programacao
          ON palestrantes.palestrante_id = programacao.palestrante_id WHERE programacao.programacao_id = $programacao_id AND palestrantes.palestrante_id = programacao.palestrante_id";
  $dados_palestrantes = $db->query($sql); 
  $dados_palestrantes = $dados_palestrantes[0];
```

Foreach to insert:

```
<label>
            Palestrantes
            <select multiple="multiple" name="palestrantes[]" placeholder="&nbsp;" class="SlectBox">
              <?php
              foreach ($lista_palestrantes as $palestrantes) {
                echo '<option value="'.$palestrantes['nome'].'">'.$palestrantes['nome'].'</option>';
              }
              ?>
            </select>
          </label>
```

Data in DB:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:20:"Alexandre";i:1;s:11:"Antonio";i:2;s:28:"Arlindo";i:3;s:25:"Carlos";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch your selected items from the database/`$_POST` and loop through them. In the html:

```
if($palestrantes['id'] == $fetched_item['id']){
    echo '<option value="'.$palestrantes['nome'].'" checked="true">'.$palestrantes['nome'].'</option>';
    //----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
else{
    echo '<option value="'.$palestrantes['nome'].'">'.$palestrantes['nome'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: @RedVulpine on second though, you may want to use `id` in stead of `name` ;)